# How to create a Hibernate/JPA trigger on Entity that would create a new entry in a table after that Entity update

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a `Vehicle` (annotated with `@EntityListeners(VehicleEventListener.class`) ) and `VehicleHistory` entities. After `Vehicle` table is updated with JPA/Hibernate I would like to insert a new entry in the `VehicleHistory` table with `Vehicle` old state information. How should I do it?

```
public class VehicleEventListener  {

  @PostUpdate
  public void onPostUpdate(Vehicle v) {
    System.out.println("POST UPDATE EXECUTED");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate, you annotate your beans with @Audit.  There are no explicit auditing features in JPA, but you can implement audit with @PrePersist, @PreUpdate, @PreRemove.  See this article:

http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: I want to achieve this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_vehicle_history()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.lastupdated <> OLD.lastupdated THEN
INSERT INTO vehiclehistory(datetime,event,latitude,longtitude,speed,vehicle_id)
VALUES(OLD.lastupdated,OLD.lastevent,OLD.latitude,OLD.longtitude,OLD.speed,OLD.id);
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;`

with update on vehicle table. It does not seem to be doing the same thing.